# Emacs. Помогите исправить функцию move-text-up

Tags: emacs

Настраиваю под себя Emacs (v 24.5.1). Нужную мне функцию для перемещения блока кода (например line или region) вверх/вниз нашел здесь: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/move-text.el
Функция корректно работает как со строкой(line), так и с блоком (region), но есть небольшая проблема при перемещении строки вверх, а именно, если становишься точкой на строку и вызываешь функцию `move-text-up`. Строка перемещается вверх один раз, точка остается на той же строке где и была. Соответственно повторное нажатие только обратно опускает ту строку, которую нужно было переместить на несколько строк выше.

Ниже привожу только конкретный фрагмент с функциями, полный текст файла можно найти по ссылке выше.

```
(defun move-text-internal (arg)
  (cond
   ((and mark-active transient-mark-mode)
    (if (> (point) (mark))
        (exchange-point-and-mark))
    (let ((column (current-column))
          (text (delete-and-extract-region (point) (mark))))
      (forward-line arg)
      (move-to-column column t)
      (set-mark (point))
      (insert text)
      (exchange-point-and-mark)
      (setq deactivate-mark nil)))
   (t
    (let ((column (current-column)))
      (beginning-of-line)
      (when (or (> arg 0) (not (bobp)))
        (forward-line)
        (when (or (< arg 0) (not (eobp)))
          (transpose-lines arg))
        (forward-line -1))
      (move-to-column column t)))))

;;;###autoload
(defun move-text-down (arg)
  "Move region (transient-mark-mode active) or current line
  arg lines down."
  (interactive "*p")
  (move-text-internal arg))

;;;###autoload
(defun move-text-up (arg)
  "Move region (transient-mark-mode active) or current line
  arg lines up."
  (interactive "*p")
  (move-text-internal (- arg)))

;;;###autoload
(defun move-text-default-bindings ()
  "Bind `move-text-up' and `move-text-down' to M-up and M-down."
  (global-set-key [M-up] 'move-text-up)
  (global-set-key [M-down] 'move-text-down))

(provide 'move-text)
```

P.S. Да, искать ошибки в чужом коде не обязательно. Возможно есть лучшее решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать модуль [shift-text](http://melpa.org/#/shift-text) из melpa. Сам какое-то время использовал ваш сниппет, но у него есть и другие проблемы.

Из [моего конфига](https://github.com/11111000000/emacs-d):

```
(use-package shift-text

  :ensure t

  :bind

  (("C-M-n" . shift-text-down)
   ("C-M-p" . shift-text-up)
   ("C-M-f" . shift-text-right)
   ("C-M-b" . shift-text-left)
   ("C-M-j" . shift-text-down)
   ("C-M-k" . shift-text-up)
   ("C-M-l" . shift-text-right)
   ("C-M-h" . shift-text-left)))
```

(помимо стандарта, для навигации я использую vim-стайл HJKL)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, вечером.

Comment: добавил конфиг в ответ

Comment: Отлично, только что попробовал - работает как нужно. И за конфиг спасибо, сам подумываю vim-стайл когда-то начать использовать